# MySqlConnection with framework 3.5

Tags: .net, mysql, database-connection

I'm doing an .NET application with Framework 3.5, I need to know the most updated version of Connector/NET with Framework 3.5, because the Connector/NET version 6.4.3 (latest) is compiled with Framework 4.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use [Connector/NET 6.3.*](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.3.html#downloads), I think. It works with MySQL 5.0 and up.

[Here is a versions table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-versions.html), but it doesn't list Connector/NET 6.4 yet.

---

Alternatively, you can download the source for 6.4. When you unzip it, there are alternative solution and project files under the `VS2008` directory that target .NET 2.0. You may encounter some errors opening `VS2008\MySQLClient.sln` due to certain project types not available, but the `MySql.Data` project (`VS2008\Source\MySql.Data\MySql.Data.csproj`) should load just fine.

Comment: Landed here looking for info on a .NET 3.5 compatible adapter for MySQL to use with a Unity3D project. For the benefit of anyone with a similar question, the most recent .NET / Mono build for mono v2.0 is Connector/Net 6.7.9

You might be able to download the current source and compile targeting .net 3.5, but if you don't want to mess with that - 6.7.9 is your easiest answer.

Comment: As of this post - MySql .NET URL: https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-net/
I was looking for the same thing as @LLL79